# find url in web page content using powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, string-matching, web-content

I need to search for https://cdn.windwardstudios.com/Archive/23.X/23.3.0/JavaRESTfulEngine-23.3.0.32.zip url from https://www.windwardstudios.com/version/version-downloads using powershell.

Thus i need `https:\\<anything>\JavaRESTfulEngine<anything>.zip`

To start off, i tried `$regexPattern = 'https://cdn\.windwardstudios\.com/Archive/\d{2}\.X/\d+\.\d+\.\d+/JavaRESTfulEngine-.*?\.zip'` which works and gives me the desired URL

To generalize further i tried `$regexPattern = 'https://cdn\.windwardstudios\.com/Archive/([^/]+)/JavaRESTfulEngine-.*?\.zip'` but now it does not work.

Below is my powershell script.

```
# URL of the website to scrape

$websiteUrl = https://www.windwardstudios.com/version/version-downloads

# Use Invoke-WebRequest to fetch the web page content

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $websiteUrl

# Check if the request was successful

if ($response.StatusCode -eq 200) {

    # Parse the HTML content to find the zip file URL using a regular expression

    $htmlContent = $response.Content

    $regexPattern = 'https://cdn\.windwardstudios\.com/Archive/([^/]+)/JavaRESTfulEngine-.*?\.zip'

    $zipFileUrls = [regex]::Matches($htmlContent, $regexPattern) | ForEach-Object { $_.Value }

    if ($zipFileUrls.Count -gt 0) {

        Write-Host "Found zip file URLs:"

        $zipFileUrls | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ }

    } else {

        Write-Host "Zip file URLs not found on the page."

    }

} else {

    Write-Host "Failed to fetch the web page. Status code: $($response.StatusCode)"

}
```

Output:

```
Zip file URLs not found on the page.
```

Desired output:

```
https://cdn.windwardstudios.com/Archive/23.X/23.3.0/JavaRESTfulEngine-23.3.0.32.zip
```

Can you please suggest?

Comment: There is a `/` where you put `[^/]*`. Try just `https://cdn\.windwardstudios\.com/Archive/(\S+?)/JavaRESTfulEngine-.*?\.zip`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it works. If I wish to `cdn\.windwardstudios\.com/Archive` as well; i tried this and it worked `https://(\S+?)/JavaRESTfulEngine-.*?\.zip`. Please post your answer for me to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
https://cdn\.windwardstudios\.com/Archive/(\S+?)/JavaRESTfulEngine-.*?\.zip
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7lyeQv/1).

*Details*:

- `https://cdn\.windwardstudios\.com/Archive/` - a literal `https://cdn.windwardstudios.com/Archive/` string
- `(\S+?)` - Group 1: one or more non-whitespace chars as few as possible
- `/JavaRESTfulEngine-` - a literal `/JavaRESTfulEngine-` string
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\.zip` - a `.zip` string.